# IsNull always returns false

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010

I'm using MS Access as a front-end for SQL Server 2012, testing for null values in a field before passing the update to the server, and displaying a helpful message to the user.

I have it working fine for one field, using `If IsNull` in the `BeforeUpdate` event, along with some fancy duplicate checking.  However, when implementing the same code for another variable, `IsNull` is always evaluating to false.

I've tried stripping out all the useful code and just using `IsNull` with a message box:

```
If IsNull(Me.M_RN) Then
    MsgBox "null!"
Else
    MsgBox "Not null!"
End If
```

This code always returns "Not null!".  If I reverse it and use :

```
If not IsNull(Me.M_RN) Then
    MsgBox "Not null!"
Else
    MsgBox "null!"
End If
```

It still returns "Not null!" every time.  I also tried other Event states e.g. `Change`, `KeyUp`, and `Dirty`.  No matter the Event, `IsNull` comes back false.

The Form objects for these fields have identical properties.  The only differences I can see are that the working variable is in `numeric(18,0)` format and not indexed, while the non-working variable is in `int` format and has a unique index.

If I remove all the code I get the `You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type` error on update.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm not sure what you mean; it's not a compile error so it doesn't show what line it's screwing up.

Comment: @McNets that's not valid vba and won't do anything

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've misread it.

Comment: Is Me.M_RN a Variant?

Comment: @McNets no, it's not

Comment: Have you tried with IsEmpty()?

Comment: It's a while since I've done MS Access VBA but... if it's a runtime error then it must break on the line that's causing the error. Or is it just somewhere in the automatic binding between the form and the table? Are you assigning the field value to a variable somewhere or is the form just directly bound to a table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm not assigning it to a variable, it's directly bound to the table (well, the query from the table)

Comment: Sounds frustrating! I came across two things in my google searches: 1. Can it be handed in the Form_Error event? 2. Is there formatting on the field confusing things? Also does this source query come from one table or many tables?

Comment: What is the field type of M_RN in SQL Server? What does it show in MS Access is the field type?

Comment: Is the non-working variable bound to an identity field in the database?

Comment: Can you print out `TypeName(Me.M_RN)` and let us know what it says?

Comment: Maybe the field is set to not allow null values?

Comment: If I remember correctly isnull(vbnull) will return False. Try: if Me.M_RN & "" = "" then  MsgBox "null!" Else
    MsgBox "Not null!"
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was based on the `not null` setting on the SQL back end table.  Access was checking the validation rule it derived from that restriction *immediately before* the `BeforeUpdate` event.

It was then popping the `You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type` error, which apparently prevents the `BeforeUpdate` event from firing at all.

Removing the `not null` restriction allowed the code to function, while retaining the unique index.

Using `Form_Error` couldn't work around it, even with `Response` set to`acDataErrContinue`.  In that case it would pop an actual runtime error about validation rules preventing changing the value on the line trying to set the field back to `.OldValue`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this part of your information is critical;

> the non-working variable is in int format and has a **unique index.**

If it has a unique index then I'm pretty sure you won't be able to assign a null value anyway. Do you have a default value set in the table?

Comment: Yes, the server bounces an error back on nulls, but it's a confusing error that can freeze Access if a non-technical user doesn't know how to deal with it properly. Hence preventing the null from going to the server in the first place.